# Merge mount points

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, xfs

Basically, I need to remove the `/home` mount point, and just use the `/` mount point.

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/mapper/rhel-root 50G 5.6G 45G 12% /
devtmpfs 7.8G 0 7.8G 0% /dev  
tmpfs 7.8G 144K 7.8G 1% /dev/shm  
tmpfs 7.8G 20M 7.8G 1% /run  
tmpfs 7.8G 0 7.8G 0% /sys/fs/cgroup  
/dev/mapper/rhel-home 142G 50M 142G 1% /home
/dev/sda1 497M 157M 340M 32% /boot  
tmpfs 1.6G 20K 1.6G 1% /run/user/0  
tmpfs 1.6G 0 1.6G 0% /run/user/1000
```

I'm running Red Hat 7. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Just to verify, these are logical volumes, yes? I presume so by the `mapper`, but want to be sure.

Comment: What kind of filesystem is `/` on? Xfs? Ext3/4?

Comment: filesystem is xfs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With all warnings about having backups, use everything at one's own risk, etc. I believe the following will work, based upon LVMs and xfs.

- Ensure all users are logged out
- Change to the console window via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>
- Login as root. Do not be a normal user and attempt to sudo, you must be root.
- On the `/` drive, `mkdir /tmp-home`
- `cp -a /home/* /tmp-home`
- Verify that the directories have been copied
- Edit the `/etc/fstab` and comment out the entry for `/home`
- Unmount the `/home` directory: `umount /home`
- Move the current `/home` mount point directory: `mv /home /home-LVM`
- Move the tmp-home directory: `mv /tmp-home /home`
- Restore the SELinux permissions: `restorecon -Rv /home`
- Reboot the system

**NOTE:** At this point, if you have an error, you can, as root again, move the /home to a backup name (e.g., `mv /home /home-failed`), restore the previous mount point (`mv /home-LVM /home`), edit the `fstab` to restore the mount, and reboot, and you will be back to where you were.

(some parts of the above approach [are also described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110899/108158))

At this point, you will have the `/home` on the `/` LVM volume directly, and the former `/home` will not be mounted. Verify this situation is correct by examining `mount` as well as `cd /home` and ensure that, e.g., `df -h .` shows the `/` drive. If all is well, then you can do `rmdir /home-LVM` to remove the previous mount point directory. Also, you can cleanup the `/etc/fstab` and remove the commented entry.

You can then use the LVM commands to delete the existing `/home` volume, and allocate the space to the `/` volume.

[Deleting the LVM:](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/LV_remove.html)

- Use `vgs` and `lvs` to list the logical volumes
- `lvremove /dev/VOLUME_GROUP/rhel-home` where VOLUME_GROUP is the appropriate group
- `pvs` should now show additional available space.

[Allocating space to the `/` LVM and growing partition:](https://www.rootusers.com/lvm-resize-how-to-increase-an-lvm-partition/)

- `lvextend -L+SIZE /dev/VOLUME_GROUP/rhel-root` where SIZE is the amount of space by which to increase the LVM. It looks like you could do up to `-L+142G` based upon the display.
- `xfs_growfs /dev/VOLUME_GROUP/rhel-root`

Comment: At `mv /tmp-home /home`, the mountpoint is still there, so maybe that needs to be `mv /tmp-home/* /home` instead? Great answer, you covered everything!

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger, you are correct. I'll post an edit shortly. Thank you!